# Are my calculations correct? 5050 LED strip 96 LEDs/m and Gledopto thin controller

Tags: power, led-driver, led-strip

So I bought Gledopto mini LED controller 5in1 and now I want to buy compatible strip.

I bought a 5050 LED strip: 5 meters with 96 LED per meter.

From what I found power consumption per LED is 0.24 W so `0.24 W * (96 * 5) = 115.2 W` - less than the max total power of the strip - 144W.

The controller also has total output current of 6 A max.

\$115.2 W / 24V = 4.8 A\$

There is also a max current per channel of 3 A, but I couldn't find this info anywhere.

Comment: Do you have a link to the LED strip? And is this the [5 in 1 Zigbee Mini Ultra Thin LED Controller](https://www.gledopto.com/h-col-396.html) you're using?

Comment: Yes this. Controller https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/33035149313.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2pol. From that i found on the description Watts 5w1 96leds: 36 W/M so too much.

Comment: Yes, 36W/m would exceed the max power. But you could always reduce the length of the LED strip, or choose a strip with fewer LEDs/m.